# Extracting {{bbox}} value of entire window in Overpass Turbo

Tags: extents, extract, overpass-turbo

I am using Overpass Turbo, quite a nice tool, but I want to extract the bbox values and use them in an osm-python-tools query.

Oddly I don't see any way to get the values of my current bbox, I don't see it in the UI anywhere, nor do I see it in the output of the Overpass QL query.

Maybe you can specify that it be output? Seems like it should be somewhere?

Comment: Not really, I just want that bbox value so I can reuse it in other things. Overpass Turbo is great for hacking around and investigating things, but once I have figured it out I want it in code.

Comment: Basically I just need to know what the bbox value so I can go to some other environment and duplicate that query.

Comment: Have you seen this topic [Overpass: Out Syntax](https://github.com/mapbox/mapping/wiki/Overpass:-Out-Syntax)?

Comment: Those are useful, I just tried the more promising ones out, but they seem to all act on individual output elements. I don't see anything that gives me the query bounding box.

Comment: That link is about exporting things in the bounding box. I don't see anything there about exporting the bbox value itself.

Answer (score 2):

Found it (a few days later). So for this:

[image]

You can go to the Export menu item and buried under "Map" and then "Current Map View" you can find this:

[image]

Still looking for a way to have it embedded in the query output though, but this will work for now.